# Laravel return same data from all action

Tags: laravel

I have a `layout` that all of my views in that a my `Controller` calls. And this `layout` needs a some data from the children to create links that relates to the controller.

I want all methods of controller to return that data.

Here is what I am doing now!

```
class PlaceController extends Controller
{

    function getEdit($id)
    {
        return $this->view('place.edit')->with(['cities' => City::all()]);
    }

    function view($view)
    {
        return view($view, ['base' => '/place']);
    }

}
```

Which means all methods `return` the `base` variable. I wanted to know if there is a more concise built in method.

Comment: Yes, you can use [view-composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers)

Comment: thanks @WhSol, can you make it an answer with a little more detail! You deserve some credit!

Comment: How you create links ? Why you need base path ? May be you can use named routes ?

Comment: I like that... how do i name controller actions?

Comment: You can read it on [Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes) 

For example you have route 

`Route::get('user/profile', 'UserController@showProfile')->name('profile');`

to now you can get link by `route('profile')`

Also if you have params on route.

`Route::get('user/profile', 'UserController@showProfile')->name('profile');`

you can pass it to link `route('profile', ['id' => 1]);`

Comment: But that is one by one! I wanted something simmilar to java annotations...

Comment: You can use [Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) and they also can have name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch the below video.. it shows how you can utilize view partials and layouts

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/25